# Will extensive use of live-view decrease the lifespan of a DSLR?

Tags: dslr, live-view

If I use the live-view regularly instead of the electronic viewfinder, will it decrease the life span of my Nikon D5100?

I want to use live-view for a manual focus lens.

- As I believe DSLR has some what a range number of actuation and switching to LV also increases the number

Comment: a) What makes you believe this is true? b) A DSLR doesn't have an electronic viewfinder - it has an optical viewfinder.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Should I be concerned about sensor heat and the development of hot pixels?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/12685/should-i-be-concerned-about-sensor-heat-and-the-development-of-hot-pixels)

Comment: Worrying about increasing the number of shutter actuations in order to use a tool the way you need to is like not writing anything to a hard drive because it will eventually wear out. And the shutter rating is no guarantee that it won't fail much earlier or last much longer than the 100,000 shutter cycles rating.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, using live view increases the number of shutter actuations and thus potentially decrease the life time of the shutter mechanism.

However I would also note that:

- The shutter can be repaired if and when it breaks, by taking the camera to your local repair shop
- You are unlikely to reach the limit unless you use your camera **a lot**
- You are holding a tool which is meant to be used, not to be kept in a glass display. If the photo you want to take requires 3 activations of the shutter instead of one, by all means, take it!