# Why does my shutter count increase by 3 or 4 with each shot?

Tags: shutter, shutter-actuations

So I've noticed this strange behavior with my Nikon D5100:
each shot increases the shutter count by 3-4 steps.

For example

- shot 1 — shutter count in EXIF is 19205
- shot 2 — shutter count in EXIF is 19209
- shot 3 — shutter count in EXIF is 19212
- shot 4 — shutter count in EXIF is 19215
- shot 5 — shutter count in EXIF is 19219

Why is this happening?

I'm using Live View. And I'm usually autofocusing.

Comment: There are several things it might be. We need more information about how you are shooting when this occurs. Through the viewfinder? In Live View?
 If so, what focus method is selected? Do you have *Auto Exposure Bracketing* or any kind of in-camera HDR enabled?

Comment: Thank you.

I'm using Live View.
Focus method is usually on Auto.

Comment: Which LV AF mode? AEB enabled? HDR?

Comment: @АнтонСимонов, please use [the edit link](https://photo.stackexchange.com/posts/96682/edit) below the tags to add the requested information; comments may be deleted at any time, and should be considered as temporary and not part of the Q&A: like sticky notes or footnotes.

Comment: This is because of using live view: https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/43604/does-live-view-increases-the-number-of-shutter-actuations

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does live view increases the number of shutter actuations?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/43604/does-live-view-increases-the-number-of-shutter-actuations)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Briefly, when using Live View mode, shutter opens up several time per photo taken:

1. Open shutter to start Live view
2. Close shutter to reset sensor to "zero" state, open shutter to expose frame
3. Close shutter after appropriate exposure time, re-open shutter to get back to Live view

If you don't take a picture, but switch camera off, then next frame will have following sequence:

1. Open shutter to start Live view; close shutter because you decided not to take picture (switched camera off or switched live view off)
2. Open shutter when you changed your mind (switched back to live view)
3. close shutter, open shutter for exposure, closed shutter after exposure
4. open shutter to get back to the live view

As you can see, you can have 3 or 4 shutter "clicks" per frame taken.